# How to mock node readline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

`getUserInput` calls a function when a user enters `y` in the CLI prompt:

```
export const getUserInput = (fn: () => void) => {
  const { stdin, stdout } = process;
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: stdin, output: stdout });
  rl.question("Can you confirm? Y/N", (answer: string) => {
    if (answer.toLowerCase() === "y") {
      fn();
    }
    rl.close();
  });
};
```

I need to create a test for `getUserInput` mocking Node's `readline`.

Currently I have tried the following  but with no success, getting:

```
TypeError: rl.close is not a function
```

Is my mock implementation correct, and if not how can I fix it?

```
jest.mock("readline");
describe.only("program", () => {
    it.only("should execute a cb when user prompt in cli y", () => {
        const mock = jest.fn();
        getUserInput(mock);
        expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
 });
```

`__mocks__/readline.ts` (directory adjacent to node_module)

```
module.exports ={
  createInterface :jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    question:jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((_questionTest, cb)=> cb('y'))
  })
}
```

Comment: No problem! Please give a [mcve] here; are you calling `jest.mock('readline')`? How is it imported in the code under test?

Comment: From the docs I linked you to: *"Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs `jest.mock('moduleName')` to be in the same scope as the require/import statement."* Don't put it inside the spec.

Comment: ^ This. Actually, you can put it inside the spec, but you need to re-import the module that uses mocked module as well.

Comment: The obvious route would be to not rely on the global `readline`, and accept `readline` as an argument (with a default), allowing you to easily pass a fake in test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding a mock the `close` function.

```
module.exports = {
  createInterface: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    question: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((_questionTest, cb) => cb("y")),
    close: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => undefined)
  })
};
```